# JavaFX TableView aparentemente recebe o valor mas mostra null

Tags: java, javafx

Ola, estou migrando meu programa para JavaFX para estudar somente, quero parar de usar Swing e passar somente o FX, mas como em uma vez anterior eu desisti devido minha dificuldade em TableView, sem delongas:
Estou com um problema, meu código pesquisa no banco de dados MySql com o JDBC drive,e retorna os dados para que eu os possa exibir na table. Porem na tabela fica "invisível", da pra clicar nos 3 campos do resultado do banco mas não mostra nada.
Minha classe Veiculo que recebe os dados do veiculo:

```js
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

/**
 *
 * @author Ramon
 */
public class Veiculo {
  private final SimpleStringProperty Marca = new SimpleStringProperty();
  private final SimpleStringProperty Modelo = new SimpleStringProperty();
  private final SimpleStringProperty Cor = new SimpleStringProperty();
  private final SimpleStringProperty Placa = new SimpleStringProperty();
  private final SimpleIntegerProperty idveiculo = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
  private final ArrayList < Veiculo > listaVeiculo;
  public Veiculo(String Marca, String Modelo, String Cor, String Placa) {
    this.Marca.set(Marca);
    this.Modelo.set(Modelo);
    this.Cor.set(Cor);
    this.Placa.set(Placa);
    listaVeiculo = new ArrayList();
  }
  public String getMusica() {
    return Marca.get();
  }

  public String getAlbum() {
    return Modelo.get();
  }

  public String getArtista() {
    return Cor.get();
  }

  public String getGenero() {
    return Placa.get();
  }

  public int getClas() {
    return idveiculo.get();
  }

  public void setMusica(String Marca) {
    this.Marca.set(Marca);
  }

  public void setAlbum(String Modelo) {
    this.Modelo.set(Modelo);
  }

  public void setArtista(String Cor) {
    this.Cor.set(Cor);
  }

  public void setGenero(String Placa) {
    this.Placa.set(Placa);
  }

  public void setClas(int idveiculo) {
    this.idveiculo.set(idveiculo);
  }

  public void adM(Veiculo v) {
    listaVeiculo.add(v);
  }
}
```

Controller da FXML onde na minha opinião o erro ocorre

```js
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author Ramon
 */
public class ExibirVeiculosDentroDaCasaController implements Initializable {@
  FXML private TableColumn clMarca;@
  FXML private TableColumn clModelo;@
  FXML private TableColumn clCor;@
  FXML private TableColumn clPlaca;@
  FXML private TableView < Veiculo > tbVeiculo;
  private ObservableList < Veiculo > listVeiculo;

  /**
   * Initializes the controller class.
   * @param url
   * @param rb
   */
  @
  Override
  public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    listVeiculo = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    assert tbVeiculo != null: "fx:id=\"tableview\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'UserMaster.fxml'.";

    try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bdestacionamento?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "");
      java.sql.Statement st = conn.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT marca,modelo,cor,placa FROM veiculo,registro WHERE registro.status =1 and registro.veiculo_idveiculo=veiculo.idveiculo ;");
      while (rs.next()) {

        Veiculo v = new Veiculo("1", "2", "3", "4");
        v.setMusica(rs.getString("marca"));
        v.setAlbum(rs.getString("modelo"));
        v.setArtista(rs.getString("cor"));
        v.setGenero(rs.getString("placa"));

        System.out.println(rs.getString("marca"));
        System.out.println(rs.getString("modelo"));
        System.out.println(rs.getString("cor"));
        System.out.println(rs.getString("placa"));
        listVeiculo.add(v);
      }
      clMarca.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Marca"));
      clModelo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Modelo"));
      clCor.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Cor"));
      clPlaca.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Placa"));
      tbVeiculo.setItems(null);// Ja pensei que poderia ser isso mas nao é
      tbVeiculo.setItems(listVeiculo);


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(ExibirVeiculosDentroDaCasaController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(ExibirVeiculosDentroDaCasaController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }@
  FXML private void btAction() {


  }
}
```

Alguém tem alguma noção ou dica ?
[image: Como podem ver ate a terceira linha da tabela da pra clicar, meio que ele "preencheu" estas linhas, mas não se exibe nada]

Como podem ver ate a terceira linha da tabela da pra clicar, meio que ele "preencheu" estas linhas, mas não se exibe nada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que você não esteja "criando" a tabela. Tente fazer o seguinte:

```
clMarca = new TableColumn<>("Marca");
```

Faça o mesmo para os demais e depois:

```
tbVeiculo.getColumns().addAll(clMarca, clModelo, clCor, clPlaca);
```

---

**Editado 04-12-2015**

Você está tendo problemas pois está usando `SimpleStringProperty`. Se você der um `sysout` na sua lista verá a forma que ela é exibida. Diante disso te proponho 2 opções:

1. Fazer a tabela baseada em `SimpleStringProperty`, nessa caso não posso te ajudar pois não conheço a propriedade, porém achei [esse tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/pt/part2/).
2. Você pode refatorar seu código para trabalhar com os tipos que o pacote `java.lang` oferece.

Exemplo:

```
public class Veiculo {
    private String MarcaC;
    private String ModeloC;
    private String CorC;
    private String PlacaC;
    private Integer idveiculo;
    private ArrayList <Veiculo> listaVeiculo;

    //Constructor
    //Get and Set's
}
```

E no Seu `controller` você pode fazer algo como isso:

```
public class ExibirVeiculosDentroDaCasaController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private TableView<Veiculo> tbVeiculo;

    private List lista;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     *
     * @param url
     * @param rb
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        //Chama o método init ao iniciar o controller
        init();

    }

    //Método que cria as colunas da tabela
    private void init() {
        TableColumn clMarca;
        TableColumn clModelo;
        TableColumn clCor;
        TableColumn clPlaca;

        clMarca = new TableColumn<>("Marca");
        clMarca.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("MarcaC"));
        clMarca.setPrefWidth(110);

        clModelo = new TableColumn<>("Modelo");
        clModelo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ModeloC"));
        clModelo.setPrefWidth(110);

        clCor = new TableColumn<>("Cor");
        clCor.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("CorC"));
        clCor.setPrefWidth(110);

        clPlaca = new TableColumn<>("Placa");
        clPlaca.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("PlacaC"));
        clPlaca.setPrefWidth(110);
        tbVeiculo.getColumns().addAll(clMarca, clModelo, clCor, clPlaca );

        //Chama o metodo que faz a consulta no banco de dados, se achar melhor pode fazer ele com retorno.
        atualizarTabela();

    }


    //MÉTODO QUE ATUALIZA A TABELA, DESSA FORMA VOCÊ NÃO PRECISARIA MAIS CLICAR EM UM BOTÃO PRA FAZER A CONSULTA.
    private void atualizarTabela() {
        //Inicializa a Lista
        lista = new ArrayList();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bdestacionamento?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "");
            java.sql.Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM veiculo,registro WHERE registro.status =1 and registro.veiculo_idveiculo=veiculo.idveiculo ;");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.err.println("TESTE");
                Veiculo v = new Veiculo("1", "2", "3", "4");
                v.setMarcaC(rs.getString("marca"));
                v.setModeloC(rs.getString("modelo"));
                v.setCorC(rs.getString("cor"));
                v.setPlacaC(rs.getString("placa"));

                System.out.println(rs.getString("marca"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("modelo"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("cor"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("placa"));
                lista.add(v);
            }
          //Preenche a tabela com os items da lista
           tbVeiculo.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(lista));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comentei o básico no código, se optar pela segunda opção e tiver alguma dúvida é só me perguntar.

**OBSERVAÇÂO:** Você vai precisar mudar algumas coisas em sua tela, se não for usar o botão não esqueça de apaga-lo. E apague também as colunas da tabela, pois elas estão sendo criadas direto no código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ainda deu o mesmo resultado :(

Comment: Vou editar a resposta. Só um momento

Comment: Editei a pergunta, se não der certo eu posto um exemplo completo pra você tentar adaptar.

Comment: Desculpe a demora eu fiquei sem internet ai agora estou na faculdade. enfim 'clMarca = new TableColumn<>("Marca");' nao foi util cria mais colunas na tabela, e o 'tbVeiculo.getColumns().addAll(clMarca, clModelo, clCor, clPlaca);' da erro quando inicia. :(

Comment: https://github.com/ramonpego/estacionamento  meu git caso necessario

Comment: caaaaaaaara você me salvou tava quase tendo que voltar pro SWING, muuuuito obrigado mesmo serio.

Comment: Por nada cara. JavaFX é bem legal e "atraente". Boa sorte :D